# mysql - convert this INNER JOIN to UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I can not get this to work. I want to convert this query to UNION to remove OR in `notifies`'s INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT posts.status, posts.reports, posts.private_id,
    enter code hereposts.parent_id, posts.post_id,
    posts.reply_counts, posts.sender, posts.content, 
    posts.image, posts.thumb, posts.date,members.username, 
    members.avatar,members.avatar_path,members.level, members.state 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN members ON posts.sender = members.member_id 
INNER JOIN notifies ON (
    posts.post_id=notifies.post_id OR posts.parent_id=notifies.post_id
) 
WHERE  (posts.date>notifies.last_date AND posts.sender<>1) 
    AND notifies.member_id=1 
    AND posts.private_id<>0 
    AND posts.status=1 
    AND posts.reports<3  
ORDER BY posts.last_update DESC, posts.date DESC LIMIT 0,25;
```

my try that not working:

```
(SELECT posts.status, posts.reports, posts.private_id , posts.parent_id, 
    posts.post_id, posts.reply_counts, posts.sender, posts.content, 
    posts.image, posts.thumb, posts.date, members.username, members.avatar,
    members.avatar_path,members.level, members.state 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN members ON posts.sender = members.member_id 
INNER JOIN notifies ON posts.parent_id=notifies.post_id) 

UNION

(SELECT posts.status, posts.reports, posts.private_id , posts.parent_id,  
    posts.post_id, posts.reply_counts, posts.sender, posts.content, 
    posts.image, posts.thumb, posts.date, members.username, members.avatar,
    members.avatar_path,members.level, members.state 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN members ON posts.sender = members.member_id 
INNER JOIN notifies ON posts.post_id=notifies.post_id) 
WHERE  (posts.date>notifies.last_date AND posts.sender<>1) 
    AND notifies.member_id=1 
    AND posts.private_id<>0
    AND posts.status=1 
    AND posts.reports<3  
ORDER BY posts.last_update DESC, posts.date DESC LIMIT 0,25;
```

Comment: Please at least put some minimal effort into formatting your SQL so that it's readable here. Expecting people to scroll right 500 characters or more just to figure out what you're asking us (and to try and make sense of it) is simply unreasonable.  If you don't put forth the effort to post a question so that it's readable, why should we put forth the effort to try and help you figure out your problem? Please [edit] to insert some line breaks and formatting. Thanks.

Comment: The 2nd query had a syntax error (parenthesis), please try it out again. Also, I'm not so sure if all this is worth it. This very simple OR statement should not be a problem. @KenWhite, I just formatted it but your comment remain more than valid considering how it was previously

Comment: @sebas thanks for the edit that is what I was trying to do but you beat me to it.

Comment: What is the whole point of the operation? Would the original statement with `OR` not be much easier to maintain? Does a `union` have performance advantages?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you only added the where clause to the last section of the UNION, and not to both.

So you went from

```
SELECT *
FROM  A INNER JOIN
B ON (a.ID = b.ID OR a.ID = b.ID2)
WHERE tada
```

to

```
SELECT *
FROM  A INNER JOIN
B ON (a.ID = b.ID)
UNION
SELECT *
FROM  A INNER JOIN
B ON (a.ID = b.ID2)
WHERE tada
```

So you need to do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM  A INNER JOIN
B ON (a.ID = b.ID)
WHERE tada
UNION
SELECT *
FROM  A INNER JOIN
B ON (a.ID = b.ID2)
WHERE tada
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change this to a `union` to make it more efficient.  Here is an alternative version (only the `from` and `where` clauses shown):

```
FROM   posts 
       INNER JOIN members 
               ON posts.sender = members.member_id 
       LEFT JOIN notifies n 
               ON ( posts.post_id = n.post_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN notifies np 
               ON ( posts.parent_id = np.post_id ) 
WHERE  ( (posts.date > n.last_date or posts.date > np.last_date)) AND posts.sender <> 1 ) 
       AND (n.member_id = 1 or np.member_id = 1)
       AND posts.private_id <> 0 
       AND posts.status = 1 
       AND posts.reports < 3
```

This also removes a duplicate row when both the parent and the post match.

I'm not positive that the date comparison is doing exactly what you want but it should be close.

Comment: @exim . . . Do you have an index on `notifies(post_id)`?

Comment: no I have another index column named `notify_id` on that table. one post may get several notifies for several members.